# ES6 won't destructure an object into pre-declared variables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

This works:

```
const { foo, bar } = someFunc();
```

And so does this:

```
let { foo, bar } = someFunc();
```

But if I try to destructure into already declared variables...

```
let foo = 0;
let bar = 0;
{ foo, bar } = someFunc();
```

then:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Is this by design? Is there a workaround other than declaring a temp object to receive the value? I'm doing this in a switch/case statement; foo and bar are declared on top and used after the switch. So far I can only do:

```
const temp = someFunc();
foo = temp.foo;
bar = temp.bar;
```

Comment: [site:stackoverflow.com javascript destructuring Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&biw=1366&bih=678&ei=QQdZWpiQBYak0gSn_JvQAw&q=+site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+destructuring+Uncaught+SyntaxError%3A+Unexpected+token&oq=+site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+destructuring+Uncaught+SyntaxError%3A+Unexpected+token&gs_l=psy-ab.3...13011.21928.0.31632.5.5.0.0.0.0.144.489.0j4.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.UMb6wd92O1I)

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate of that -- but with a **much** better title and clearer text, too. So hopefully this duplicate sticks around.

Comment: Indeed, I could not find that earlier question. But it does provide the correct answer: `({ foo, bar } = someFunc());`